# Django - getting the value of date in html input tag

Tags: python, html, django, django-models

I'm trying to set a date as the value of a date input in a form. But, as your may have guessed, it's not working.
Here's what I have in my template:

```
<form method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}

<label for="address">Address:</label>
<textarea name="address">{{user.address}}</textarea>
<label for="DOB">DOB:</label>
<input type="date" name="DOB" value="{{user.dob|date:'Y-m-d'}}">    
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
<button type="reset">Reset</button>
<a href="{% url 'view_profile' %}">cancel</a>
```

Here is my model:

```
sys_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, blank=True)
email = models.EmailField(
    verbose_name='email address',
    max_length=255,
    unique=True,
)
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True)
address = models.TextField(max_length=300,blank=True,null=True)
DOB = models.DateField('Date of Birth', blank=True, null=True)
DOJ = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
staff = models.BooleanField(default=False) # a admin user; non super-user
admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Here is my form:

```
class EditProfileForm(UserChangeForm):
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('address','DOB','password')
```

Here is my Views:

```
def edit_profile(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    user_form = EditProfileForm(request.POST or None,instance=request.user)
    if user_form.is_valid(): 
        user_form.save()
        return redirect('view_profile')
else:
    user_form = EditProfileForm(request.POST or None,instance=request.user)
return render(request,'edit_profile.html',{'user_form':user_form,})
```

I have 2 problems
1: when I am editing my profile unable to get the value of Date of birth in my edit page.
2: while registration I am unable to get the calendar in the form registration so I can't tell the user format of entering the DOB its just Displaying type = "text" in registration

```
  <h2>Sign up</h2>
  <form  method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ user_form.as_p }}
   <button type="submit">Sign up</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: 1. `user.dob|` ==> `user.DOB|`

Comment: `{{user.dob|date:'Y-m-d'}}` where is `user` , did u add `user` in context

Comment: 2. for calendar you need use js or `placeholder`

Comment: Thanks, @BearBrown my 1st question, is answered and I didn't see about it capitalization and my 2nd question how can I use js in models

Comment: not in the model in the template

Comment: ok Thanks for the suggestion @BearBrown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{{user.DOB|date:'Y-m-d'}}
```

I think you misspelled word.

Comment: This only answers one part of the question and I believe Bear Brown was the first to point to the problem with how `dob` was misspelled. I would call this unethical stealing of the points, @marin.